# Can't able to store input data in firestore kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the code

```
val db = Firebase.firestore

val user = hashMapOf(
    "name" = "{binding.edit_name.text.toString()}",
    "email" = "{binding.edit_email.text.toString()}
)
binding.submitBtn.setOnClickListener{
    db.collection("users").add(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
}
```

In above code edit_name , edit_text is input taken by keyboard. I can't able to store the user in firestore. I think there is problem of converting bindig.edit_name.text.toString() it can't able to convert string.
If i use hash map without taking input from keyboard as below then I am able to insert data in firestore.

```
val user = hashMapOf(
    "name" to "ABC",
    "email" to "abc@gmail.com"
)
```

This hash map is able to add in firestore.

*I think there is problem in **binding** and I am also can't able to toast bindg.edit_name.toString() as shown below*

```
binding.submitBtn.setOnClickListener{
    Toast.makeText(context,"${binding.edit_name.text.toString()},Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Please help in this. I think all problem is that I can't able to convert binding data value as a string (by default it is **Editable**).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) your code seems fine from the point of view of inserting data.

The issue seems indeed to rely on "**binding.variable_input.text.toString()**".

While investigating the Android Data Binding Library I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185390/kotlin-tostring-not-available-in-android-databinding) post, which recommends instead of using `toString()`, use:

- `String.valueOf()`, or if you want to use *toString()*, try
- `Integer.valueOf().toString()`

Comment: Your suggested link and answer for xml not for fragment. I want to convert binding data in kotlin fragment file then I want to add in database. Without converting in string it is not able to insert in db because type of binding data is Editable.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further on how you are storing the text input in binding?

Comment: I have taken input from keyboard then I stored in variable using binding `val name = binding.name.text.toString()` but due to this I can't able store in db... If you see above my ques with code my question will be cleared

Comment: If I am using binding in my fragment then if we take input from keyboard then that input will be visible in **Kotlin file** by binding.text.toString() but it is not able to add in db

Answer (score 1):

1. Expressions cannot be used for assignments in HashMap, so probably worth changing `hashMapOf( "name" to "{binding.name.text.toString()}", "email" to "{binding.email.text.toString()}")`
2. Better assign `val name = binding.name.text.toString()` and then `hashMapOf( "name" to name)`
3. Even better to create a custom object and set the values.

   `data class UserInfo (val name: String? = "",val email: String? = "") { constructor(): this("","")}`